# Php DateTime not working when I Convert AD

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<span class="event-summary__month">
    <?php
        $eventDate = new DateTime(get_field('event_date'));
        echo $eventDate->format('M');
    ?>
</span>
```

when i run this, down error shows

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (06-28-2014
>   07:43:58 ) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character

Comment: it is a date and return format is 'Ymd'. I set it by acf plugin

Answer (score 1):

May be your date in wrong format, Instead you can use `createFromFormat` method

```
$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y h:i:s', '06-28-2014 07:43:58');
echo $eventDate->format('M');
```

[Live demo link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df8210b10ee5e58e9d9a0a77dd23e6938adb24c7)

Comment: Its not wrong. Actually When I convert my date from AD to another format by a plugin, this error comes up

Comment: @Afshin: I am not sure but `DateTime` takes date in `Y-m-d` not `m-d-Y`, By the way is your problem solved with above code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$date= get_field('event_date', false);
$date= DateTime::createFromFormat('M H:i:s', $date);

echo $date->format('M');
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Can check with above code

Comment: this is close but the format used to create the date is wrong and will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

How about using Carbon?

```php
$eventDate = Carbon::parse(get_field('event_date'))->format('M');
echo $eventDate;
```

Comment: What is Carbon?